# Simple calculator in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to write a calculator in HTML. I really can't find what is going wrong and it does not show the results. I can't find something wrong can you help? I'm running it in Chrome.

JavaScript File and and the HTML:

```js
showresult(choise){
var n1=parsefloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
var n2=parsefloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
var r;
var c=choise;

switch(c)
 {
 case '1':
  r=n1+n2;
  break;
 case '2':
  r=n1-n2;
  break;
 case '3':
  r=n1*n2;
  break;
 case '4': 
  r=n1/n2;
  break;
 case '5':
  r=n2*100/n1;
  break;
 default:
  break;
   
 }
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=r;

 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<script src="calculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h1>My calculator</h1>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="600">
<tr align="center">
<td>First number</td>
<td>Second Number</td>
<td>Result</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td><input name="number1" type="text" size=10 id='num1'/></td>
<td><input name="number2" type="text" size=10 id='num2'/></td>
<td> <input type="text" id='result' readonly ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<button onclick="showresult('1')">+</button>
<button onclick="showresult('2')">-</button>
<button onclick="showresult('3')">*</button>
<button onclick="showresult('4')">/</button>
<button onclick="showresult('5')">%</button>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simple calculator on "html" or JS?

Comment: html with a javascript file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things to fix:
1) Assign to `value`, not `innerHTML`, when referring to an `input` element. (They have no content, hence no `innerHTML`.
2) Start a function declaration with the keyword `function`.
3) It’s `parseFloat`, not `parsefloat`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Minimally fixed code:

```js
function showresult(choise){
var n1=parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
var n2=parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
var r;
var c=choise;

switch(c)
 {
 case '1':
  r=n1+n2;
  break;
 case '2':
  r=n1-n2;
  break;
 case '3':
  r=n1*n2;
  break;
 case '4': 
  r=n1/n2;
  break;
 case '5':
  r=n2*100/n1;
  break;
 default:
  break;
   
 }
document.getElementById('result').value=r;

 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<script src="calculator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h1>My calculator</h1>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="600">
<tr align="center">
<td>First number</td>
<td>Second Number</td>
<td>Result</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td><input name="number1" type="text" size=10 id='num1'/></td>
<td><input name="number2" type="text" size=10 id='num2'/></td>
<td> <input type="text" id='result' readonly ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<button onclick="showresult('1')">+</button>
<button onclick="showresult('2')">-</button>
<button onclick="showresult('3')">*</button>
<button onclick="showresult('4')">/</button>
<button onclick="showresult('5')">%</button>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beat me to it... but here's a plnkr that shows it in action. http://plnkr.co/edit/UT0FhVjbEZu5iv1J1ZVj?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `innerHTML` property of an input, which doesn't work
because inputs have `value` property, if you want to show text/data in them.

you should change this line:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=r;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('result').value = r;
```

on creating a calculator in simple javascript, also check this tutorial out that i wrote,  it may help you:
[Create a calulator in javascript - Tutorial by 10code.dev](https://10code.dev/javascript/a-simple-calculator-in-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cnum = document.getElementsByClassName('c-num')[0];
var cope = document.getElementsByClassName('c-operator')[0];
var intom = document.getElementById('intop');
var inbottom = document.getElementById('inbottom');
var newinbottom;
var newinbottom2;
var sign;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 cnum.innerHTML +='<span class="numb" value="'+i+'" id="numid'+i+'" onclick="puton('+i+')">'+i+'</span>';
}
document.getElementById('numid0').style.order = "1";
function puton(numb){
  inbottom.value += numb 
}
function ans(answer){
 //console.log(sign)
  if(inbottom.value ==''){
     alert('type input');
     }else if(sign == "plus"){
  newinbottom2 = inbottom.value;
  intom.value = inbottom.value;
   inbottom.value = parseInt(newinbottom) + parseInt(newinbottom2);   
 }else if(sign == "minus"){
    newinbottom2 = inbottom.value;
  intom.value = inbottom.value;
   inbottom.value = newinbottom - newinbottom2;
    }else if(sign == "divi"){
    newinbottom2 = inbottom.value;
  intom.value = inbottom.value;
   inbottom.value = newinbottom / newinbottom2;
    }else if(sign == "mul"){
    newinbottom2 = inbottom.value;
  intom.value = inbottom.value;
   inbottom.value = newinbottom * newinbottom2;
    }
   
   sign ='';
 
}
function opr(opra){
 if(sign != '' && sign != undefined){
  ans();
 }
 else if(opra == "clr"){
     intom.value =''
     inbottom.value ='';
    newinbottom='';
    newinbottom='';
     sign ='';
    }
 else if(opra == "plus"){
 newinbottom = inbottom.value;
 intom.value = inbottom.value;
 inbottom.value = '';
  sign = "plus";
 }else if(opra == "minus"){
 newinbottom = inbottom.value;
 intom.value = inbottom.value;
 inbottom.value = '';
    sign = "minus";
    }else if(opra == "divi"){
  newinbottom = inbottom.value;
 intom.value = inbottom.value;
 inbottom.value = '';
    sign = "divi";
    }else if(opra == "mul"){
  newinbottom = inbottom.value;
 intom.value = inbottom.value;
 inbottom.value = '';
    sign = "mul";
    }
}
```

```css
.main{
 width:100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }
 .c-body {
    width: 400px;
    height: 255px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid;
 }
 .c-num{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .c-operator{
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
 .c-row{
  display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
 }
 .c-operator [id^='numid']{
 width: 90px;
 flex-direction: initial;
 }
 [id^='numid'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
 flex-direction: inherit;
}
 .c-minputs .inbox{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }
 [id^='numid']:hover{
  background: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="c-body">
   <div class="c-minputs">
    <input id="intop" type="number" class="topin inbox" disabled>
   <input id="inbottom" type="number" class="bottomin inbox" placeholder="Type Here">
 </div>
 <div class="c-row">
 <div class="c-num">
   
   </div>
   <div class="c-operator">
  <span class="numb" id="numidplus" onclick="opr('plus')">+</span>
  <span class="numb" id="numidminus" onclick="opr('minus')">-</span>
  <span class="numb" id="numiddiv" onclick="opr('divi')">/</span>
  <span class="numb" id="numidmul" onclick="opr('mul')">*</span>
  <span class="numb" id="numidans" onclick="ans('answer')">=</span>
  <span class="numb" id="numidclr" onclick="opr('clr')">c</span>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the function correctly.

```
function showresult(choise) {
/* ... */
}
```

Also, remember that Javascript is case sensitive therefore the right way to parse a float is
`parseFloat()`
Lastly, as pointed out by gillesc, use the attribute `value` on the input element.
`document.getElementById('result').value=r;`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace "**innerHTML"** to **"value"** in your code.

If you want to access the text within a non-input HTML element, then you are going to have to use the innerHTML property instead of value

***Now code becomes:***

```
document.getElementById('result').value=r;
```

*Here we used the value property that all input elements have to use to grab the value the user enters.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your code

```
function calc(form) {
      var D = "0";
      var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
      var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
      var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;

      switch(B){
          case'+':
          D= parseInt(A)+parseInt(C); break;
          case'-':
          D= parseInt(A)-parseInt(C); break;
          case'*':
          D=parseInt(A)*parseInt(C); break;
          case'/':
          D=parseInt(A)/parseInt(C); break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>

 var num1;
 var op;
 
 function pressBtn(value){
  var prev = document.forms["calc"]["display"].value;
  if (!(prev == "" && value==0)){
   var newval = prev+value;
   document.forms["calc"]["display"].value = newval;
  }
   
 }
 
 function pressOP(operator){
  op = operator;
  var display = document.forms["calc"]["display"].value;
  num1 = parseInt(display);
  document.forms["calc"]["display"].value = "";
 }
 
 function pressEq(){
  var display = document.forms["calc"]["display"].value;
  var num2 = parseInt(display);
  switch(op){
   case "P":
    var ans=num1+num2;
    break;
   case "M":
    var ans=num1-num2;
    break; 
  }
  document.forms["calc"]["display"].value = ans;
 }
</script>
```

```css
<style>
 input[type=button]{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 5px;
 } 
 input[type=text]{
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: right;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<body style="background: #ccc;">
 <div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; background: #fff; text-align: center">
  <form name="calc">
   <input type="text" name="display" readonly ><br>
   <input type="button" name="btn7" value="7" onClick="pressBtn(7)">
   <input type="button" name="btn8" value="8" onClick="pressBtn(8)">
   <input type="button" name="btn9" value="9" onClick="pressBtn(9)"><br>
   <input type="button" name="btn4" value="4" onClick="pressBtn(4)">
   <input type="button" name="btn5" value="5" onClick="pressBtn(5)">
   <input type="button" name="btn6" value="6" onClick="pressBtn(6)"><br>
   <input type="button" name="btn1" value="1" onClick="pressBtn(1)">
   <input type="button" name="btn2" value="2" onClick="pressBtn(2)">
   <input type="button" name="btn3" value="3" onClick="pressBtn(3)"><br>
   <input type="button" name="btn0" value="0" onClick="pressBtn(0)">
            <input type="button" name="btnPlus" value="+" onClick="pressOP('P')" >
            <input type="button" name="btnPlus" value="-" onClick="pressOP('M')" ><br>
            <input type="button" name="btnEq" value="=" onClick="pressEq();" >
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>stackoverflow</title>

    <style>
        body{
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
        }
    .button {
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #276873;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #599bb3 5%, #408c99 100%);
        background-color: #599bb3;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #29668f;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 21px 6px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3d768a;
        height: 50px;
        width: 80px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .button:hover {
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #408c99 5%, #599bb3 100%);
        background-color:#408c99;
    }
    form>input{
        height: 40px;
        width: 329px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: none;
        margin-left: 500px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    table{
        margin-left: 500px;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

        <form name="form">
            <input name="textview"> 
        </form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="Clear" onClick="c()"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7" onClick="insert(7)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8" onClick="insert(8)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9" onClick="insert(9)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="/" onClick="insert('/')"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4" onClick="insert(4)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5" onClick="insert(5)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6" onClick="insert(6)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="-" onClick="insert('-')"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1" onClick="insert(1)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2" onClick="insert(2)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3" onClick="insert(3)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="+" onClick="insert('+')"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0" onClick="insert(0)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="." onClick="insert('.')"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="=" onClick="equal('=')"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="*" onClick="insert('*')"></td>

                </tr>
            </table>


    </div>

    <script>
        function insert(num){
            document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value+num;
        }
        function equal(){
            let exp = document.form.textview.value;
            if(exp){
                document.form.textview.value = eval(exp)
            }
            else{
                console.log('Something Wrong')
            }
        }
        function c(){
            document.form.textview.value = null;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be significantly improved by some explanation, rather than just code. Please see [answer].